# Running totals with initial value then adding the totals as stated by the date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Imagine we have a table:

```
SELECT SUM(A) AS TOTALS,DATE,STUFF FROM TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN 'DATESTART' AND 'DATEEND'
GROUP BY DATE,STUFF
```

Normally this gets the totals as:

```
totals stuff    date
23      x      01.01.1900
3       x      02.01.1900
44      x      06.01.1900
```

But what if we have the previous the data before the startdate,and i want to add those initial data to my startdate value; for example; from the begining of time i already have a sum value of x lets say 100
so i want my table to start from 123 and add the previous data such as:
123
126
126+44 and so on...

```
totals stuff    date
123      x      01.01.1900
126      x      02.01.1900
170      x      06.01.1900
```

How can i achieve that?

Source data:

```
WITH    Stocks
          AS (
               SELECT
                Dep.Dept_No ,
                SUM(DSL.Metre) AS Metre ,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 112) AS Date
               FROM
                DS (NOLOCK) DSL
                JOIN TBL_Depts (NOLOCK) Dep ON Dep.Dept_No = DSL.Dept
               WHERE
                1 = 1 AND
                DSL.Sil = 0 AND
                DSL.Depo IN ( 5000, 5001, 5002, 5003, 5004, 5014, 5018, 5021, 5101, 5109, 5303 ) AND
                Dep.Dept_No NOT IN ( 6002 ) AND
                Dep.Dept_No IN ( 6000, 6001, 6003, 6004, 6005, 6011, 6024, 6030 ) AND
                DSL.Date BETWEEN '2013-06-19' AND '2013-06-20'
               GROUP BY
                Dep.Dept_No ,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 112)
             )
    SELECT
        Stocks.Metre ,
        Dep.Dept AS Dept ,
        Stocks.Date
    FROM
        Stocks
        LEFT JOIN TBL_Depts (NOLOCK) Dep ON Stocks.Dept = Dep.Dept
    ORDER BY
        Stocks.Metre DESC
```

Comment: Please add your database engine as the solution is likely to be RDBMS specific

Answer (score 2):

Any RDBMS with window and analytic functions (SQL Server 2012, PostgreSQL but not MySQL)

```
SELECT
    SumA + SUM(SumARange) OVER (ORDER BY aDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS TOTALS,
    other, aDate
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        SUM(a) AS SumARange,
        other, aDate
    FROM
        SomeTable
    WHERE
        aDate BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20130106'
    GROUP BY
        other, aDate
    ) X
    CROSS JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        SUM(a) AS SumA
    FROM
        SomeTable
    WHERE
        aDate < '20130101'
    ) Y
ORDER BY
    aDate;
```

or

```
SELECT
    SUM(SumA) OVER () + SUM(SumARange) OVER (ORDER BY aDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS TOTALS,
    other, aDate
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN aDate < '20130101' THEN a ELSE 0 END) AS SumA,
        SUM(CASE WHEN aDate BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20130106' THEN a ELSE 0 END) AS SumARange,
        other, aDate
    FROM
        SomeTable
    WHERE
        aDate <= '20130106'
    GROUP BY
        other, aDate
    ) X
ORDER BY
    aDate;
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5bc0/7) and [another](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5bc0/6)

Comment: 100 is a dynamic value btw,its also a sum of A,from the beginning of time until my initial startdate...

Comment: @Sin5k4: add more source data please, not just pre aggregated data

Comment: for somre reason this doesnt give me the proper results;checked via fiddle,wont the totals increase?

Comment: Cheers but for some reason i can not run the sums,i get: Operand data type datetime is invalid for sum operator. error.

Comment: @Sin5k4: there is no datetime SUM in my code, therefore you have adopted it wrong. It works on SQL Fiddle with int values

Comment: Sorry my mistake was using the wrong column there,but i guess this is incompatible with sqlserver2005 :( Cant get it to run;

Answer (score 0):

Use option with APPLY operator to calculate the totals. You need also add additional CASE expression in the GROUP BY clause

```
;WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT SUM(a) AS sumA, [stuff], MAX([Date]) AS [Date]
 FROM SomeTable
 WHERE [Date] <= '20130106'
 GROUP BY [stuff], CASE WHEN [Date] <= '20130101' THEN 1 ELSE [Date] END
 )
 SELECT o.total, [stuff], [Date]
 FROM cte c CROSS APPLY (
                         SELECT SUM(c2.sumA) AS total
                         FROM cte c2
                         WHERE c.[Date] >= c2.[Date]
                         ) o
```

See example on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e23f3/1)